# What attributes should a samurai build focus on in Elden Ring?

Tags: elden-ring

Hey guys I am doing a samurai build, I started as a samurai, I am currently level 46 and have two Uchigatanas, one is leveled up to +4, the other is regular. My attributes are: vigor (23), mind (12), endurance (19), strength (14), dexterity (32), intelligence (9), failt & arcane (8).

Leveling up is getting expensive so I was wondering how should I spend my runes.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Term

Your top priority should be to get 30-40 Vigor to increase your survivability. It's around 30 Vigor that you begin to see a better return on investment from pumping points into health. Around 40 Vigor, you'll have ~1400 HP, which significantly increases your chances of surviving against most mobs.

### Long Term

Invest in either Strength or Dex, depending on the types of weapons you want to use.

When inspecting weapons in your inventory, you should see letters below the stat requirements. These denote the weapon's attribute scaling, from `E` (very poor scaling) to `S` (very good).

In Elden Ring, the Uchigatana has an initial scaling of `D/D` for Strength and Dexterity, respectively. But according to [the Fextralife entry on the Uchigatana](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Uchigatana), once upgraded to +25, a standard Uchigatana has a scaling of `D/C`, making it slightly better for Dex than for Strength.

*However*, this assumes a standard infusion. A Keen ("sharp") +25 Uchigatana has a scaling of A in Dex. Lkewise, a Heavy +25 Uchigatana has a scaling of A in Strength.

So the answer is that it depends. Do you want to make a quality build, where you invest an equal number of levels in strength and dex to give yourself access to a wide range of weapons? Or do you want to favor Dex or Strength? That in turn will influence how you infuse your weapon. Something to consider as part of this decision is whether you intend to use the Uchigatana (and similar weapons) on this character, or if you might one day want to use something else.

As a rule of thumb: If a weapon is sharp and pointy, it *probably* scales with Dex. Examples include spears, rapiers, daggers, curved swords, katanas, and other weapons typically associated with agility, like bows. (There are exceptions to this rule, though.) For example, if you browse the Fextralife page on [Katanas in general](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Katanas) (spoilers!), you'll find that most of them scale with Dex.